# Matlab: Sorting rows in ascending order but tracking original index

Tags: matlab

I have an array 'A' of size 50 x 10 filled with doubles.

I want to arrange each row in ascending order to get a new array 'B' but I want to create a third array 'C' where I keep track of the index from original array 'A'

E.g.

Array A (original array):

```
11   9   13   10
12   4   1    6  
13   5   12   12
```

Array B (rearranged array):

```
9   10   11   13
1   4    6    12
5   12   12   13
```

Array C (tracking index from array A):

```
2   4    1    3
3   2    4    1
2   3    4    1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried sort:

```
[b, c] = sort(A,2)
```

Answer (score 4):

The second output of sort is exactly what you want.

```
[B, C] = sort(A, 2);
```